# Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'value') React Functional Components

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Hi I am trying to learn react and using the react guide from the react website in there is an example to called lifting the state up. The example is in class components I am trying to use functional components. The link to orginal example [website link][1]

I am getting cannot read properties of undefied in react. Not sure what to look for

```html
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import TempratureInputComponent from './TempratureInputComponent';

const TempratureCalculatorComponent = () => {
  const [waterTemprature, setwaterTemprature] = useState('');
  const [tempratureScale, settempratureScale] = useState('c');

  const handleCelsiusChange = (e) => {
    console.log(typeof e.target.value);
    const temp = Number(e.target.value);
    // console.log(waterTemprature);
    setwaterTemprature(temp);
    settempratureScale('c');
  };
  const handleFahrenheitChange = (e) => {
    // console.log(waterTemprature);
    setwaterTemprature(e.target.value);
    settempratureScale('f');
  };
  const toCelsius = (fahrenheit) => {
    return ((fahrenheit - 32) * 5) / 9;
  };
  const toFahrenheit = (celsius) => {
    return (celsius * 9) / 5 + 32;
  };
  const tryConvert = (waterTemprature, convertTo) => {
    const input = parseFloat(waterTemprature);
    if (Number.isNaN(input)) {
      return '';
    }
    const output = convertTo(input);
    const rounded = Math.round(output * 1000) / 1000;
    return rounded.toString();
  };
  const celsius =
    tempratureScale === 'f'
      ? tryConvert(waterTemprature, toFahrenheit)
      : waterTemprature;
  const fahrenheit =
    tempratureScale === 'c'
      ? tryConvert(waterTemprature, toCelsius)
      : waterTemprature;

  return (
    <>

      <TempratureInputComponent
        tempratureScale='c'
        waterTemprature={celsius}
        onTempratureChange={handleCelsiusChange}
      />
      <TempratureInputComponent
        tempratureScale='f'
        waterTemprature={fahrenheit}
        onTempratureChange={handleFahrenheitChange}
      />
    </>
  );
};

export default TempratureCalculatorComponent;
```

```html
/* eslint-disable comma-dangle */
/* eslint-disable react/prop-types */
import React from 'react';

const TempratureInputComponent = ({
  tempratureScale,
  waterTemprature,
  onTempratureChange,
}) => {
  const scaleNames = {
    c: 'Celsius',
    f: 'Fahrenheit',
  };
  const handleTempratureChange = (e) => {
    console.log(e.target.value);
    onTempratureChange(e.target.value);
  };
  return (
    <div>
      <fieldset>
        <legend>Enter temperature in {scaleNames[tempratureScale]}</legend>
        <input value={waterTemprature} onChange={handleTempratureChange} />
      </fieldset>
    </div>
  );
};

export default TempratureInputComponent;
```

```html
import "./App.css";
import TempratureCalculatorComponent from "./Components/TempratureCalculatorComponent";
const App = () => (
  <div className="App">
    <TempratureCalculatorComponent />
  </div>
);

export default App;
```

Comment: https://codepen.io/gaearon/pen/jGBryx?editors=0010. link to the example site

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are passing the value to `onTempratureChange` not the `e` object

```
  const handleTempratureChange = (e) => {
    console.log(e.target.value);
    onTempratureChange(e.target.value);
  };
```

> As you can see in the above snippet you are passing value i.e
> `e.target.value` as an argument into the `onTempratureChange`
> function. So If I typt input in to the `input` element as `1` then you are passing `1` not the `event` object itself

So there are 2 method to solve this

**1)** Either send the value as argument

```
  const handleTempratureChange = (e) => {
    console.log(e.target.value);
    onTempratureChange(e.target.value);
  };
```

**Live Demo**

[image: Codesandbox Demo]

and receive the `value` as parameter. So you should get the value in the `onTempratureChange`

```
  const handleCelsiusChange = (value) => {
    console.log(typeof value);
    const temp = Number(value);
    // console.log(waterTemprature);
    setwaterTemprature(temp);
    settempratureScale("c");
  };
```

**2)** or you can send `event` object to `onTempratureChange` as:

```
  const handleTempratureChange = (e) => {
    onTempratureChange(e);
  };
```

**Live Demo**

[image: Codesandbox Demo]

and get the `e` object as a parameter in `onTempratureChange` function as:

```
  const handleCelsiusChange = (e) => {
    const temp = Number(e.target.value);
    setwaterTemprature(temp);
    settempratureScale("c");
  };
```

Comment: Thank you so much, can you please break down what is happening, I am having a hardtime understanding controlled components

Comment: Edited, please have a look